# Check if file in different directory is the same as original

Tags: php

I´ve tried some things now with minor to no success.

What i've tried so far is this:

```
echo sha1_file("development/index.php")." <- Dev<br>"; // 39e7851f050051abf91eb0791ae6a87084113dd9
echo sha1_file("customer/index.php")." <- Customer"; //17c64da656fae781dd404bbdc10fd2bcb58e12d9
```

and

```
echo filesize("development/index.php")." <- Dev<br>"; //369711 
echo filesize("customer/index.php")." <- Customer"; //363338
```

and this

```
echo filemtime("development/index.php")." <- Dev<br>"; // 1422516938 
echo filemtime("customer/index.php")." <- Customer"; // 1422516943
```

The files are the same - I copied the one from development to customer with filezilla.

I think the sha1_-/md5 didn't work because of the different `filetime`.

How can I check for sure that the file in the path `customer/index.php` is the same as in `development/index.php` ?

For anyone else facing the same problem: The files were not **identical**!

Solving this problem to make sure the files are really identical:

```
copy('development/index.php', 'customer/index.php'); // copy file

echo sha1_file("development/index.php")." <- Dev<br>";
echo sha1_file("customer/index.php")." <- Cust<br>";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verifying that two files are identical using pure PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849927/verifying-that-two-files-are-identical-using-pure-php)

Comment: Are you sure the file is identical? filesize should be the same for the same file, regardless of its creation or modification times. You might want to take a smaller file, so you can check by hand if it really is different from each other

Comment: The files are not the same. Filezilla probably changed the line endings.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say they aren't the same

Comment: I reuploaded them from disk to both directories and it worked...I made a mistake somewhere...also didn't find the other question but @MarkusMüller pointed at my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both files have different names, and different `filetime` values, then naturally their hashes will be different. If you want to know whether or not the *content* of both files is identical, you'll have to compare the hashes of the content, or simply compare the content as a whole:

```
$contentHash1 = sha1(file_get_contents($file1));
$contentHash2 = sha1(file_get_contents($file2));
echo 'Hash 1: ', $contentHash1, '<br>Hash 2: ', $contentHash2;
```

If these hashes still don't match, try `trim` on the content strings (an extra line in one of the files is easy to miss, and make sure the encoding is the same in both files.

Comment: This is not true, sha1_file only looks at the content of the file, so `sha1_file($file) == sha1(file_get_contents($file))`

Comment: @BartHaalstra: They're not exactly the same, since `file_get_contents` doesn't use the stream API by default (for that you have to specify a `$context` yourself). `sha1_file` does (and I believe it reads the file in binary mode, `file_get_contents` creates a `zval` string

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try some tool that allows compare by content (for example total commander)

Then look for what are the differences and that will give you some insight why your sha method wasn't working and maybe what else to do if you want to compare files in php.