# How to compare two SQL file query structure in PHP

Tags: php

I have two sql files(t1.sql and t2.sql). Two sql files are different versions and two files contains create queries. I want to compare two sql files query to check the query structures are changed or not.

**For example**:-

```
t1.sql file:
CREATE TABLE `static_ids` (
  `access_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `group_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`access_id`,`group_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

t2.sql file:
CREATE TABLE `static_ids` (
  `access_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `group_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `group_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`access_id`,`group_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

In this example, create query for the table `static_ids` structure is different.

Kindly give any idea to compare two sql file queries through PHP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use file\_get\_contents() to compare two files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060125/can-i-use-file-get-contents-to-compare-two-files)

Comment: If any additional white space exists means it wouldnt work.
I wanna to check each sql file queries structure exactly.

Answer (score 1):

To reliably check if the structure is the same using only PHP, you would basically have to rewrite the MySQL parser. It would have to understand, for instance, that

```
id     int;
```

is equivalent to

```
`id` int(11) signed DEFAULT NULL;
```

The much easier solution is to just run the `CREATE TABLE` command on a blank MySQL database, then do `DESCRIBE table_name to a get a list of all the columns that were created as. You can then run through the list of columns for the two tables in a PHP`for` loop and compare them.